# NPOI export excel directly to frontend without saving it on server

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to write an excel file (with NPOI) directly to browser without saving it first on the server.

I tried following in my controller without success:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportExcel(){

    var fs = new MemoryStream();

    IWorkbook workbook;
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Test);

    IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("ID");
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Name");

    row = excelSheet.CreateRow(1);
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(1);
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("User 1");

    workbook.Write(fs);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);


    return File(bytes, "application/vnd.ms-excel", sampleType.Abbreviation+".xlsx"); 
}
```

When executing above method I always get following error:

```
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

...
System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Length()
byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
...
```

Or is their another great nuget package to handle (read and write) excel files without storing files on server?

**PS: I am using dotnet core 2.1 en nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write directly to the `Response.Body`.
2. Because Excel is treated as an attachment, we also need to set the `Response.Headers`

To make life easy, we can create an extension method firstly:

```
public static class IWorkBookExtensions {

    public static void WriteExcelToResponse(this IWorkbook book, HttpContext httpContext, string templateName)
    {
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateName))
        {
            var contentDisposition = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            contentDisposition.SetHttpFileName(templateName);
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = contentDisposition.ToString();
        }
        book.Write(response.Body);
    }
}
```

and now we can export the excel file directly :

```
public async Task ExportExcel(){

    IWorkbook workbook;
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Test");

    IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("ID");
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Name");

    row = excelSheet.CreateRow(1);
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(1);
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("User 1");

    workbook.WriteExcelToResponse(HttpContext,"test.xlsx");
}
```

[image]

Comment: AWESOME !! just what I was looking!